# Why won't this formtastic CSS override in my Rails 3 application?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

So I have an **application.css** file with the following:

```
.formtastic.clouds .fields .inputs OL LI
{
    float: left;
    width: 290px;
    margin-bottom: -20px;
}
```

Then I have a **changes.css** with the following:

```
.formtastic.clouds .fields .inputs ol li
{
    float: left;
    width: 280px;
    margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px !important;
}
```

I want changes.css to override application.css.  The !important clause does nothing - when I look in chrome dev tools it still computes the properties using application.css settings.  This is true whether or not I have a "margin-bottom: 0px !important" in changes.css.

I have to change application.css to this to notice any appreciable results:

```
.formtastic.clouds .fields .inputs OL LI
{
    float: left;
    width: 290px;
    /*margin-bottom: -20px;*/
    margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
}
```

It should be noted that application.css is called after changes.css in the Rails request on my localhost, so this leads me to suspect that it's simply the case that this is what's causing it.  Is this the case?

Answer (score 1):

did you try it on firefox? i had similar problems with chrome and !important tag and this was because some parent html element in chrome blocked !important so i had to fix parent css or something like that don't exactly remember now but maybe it will help you to look in other parts of code not just these two css ...

Answer (score 0):

OL, LI? shouldn't it be **`ol, li`**?

*Order in which you require your files in application.css does matter, **the ones which are required below will override the styles of upper ones(provided they have same specificity as in your case)*** but since ***you are using !important so it shouldn't really matter*** unless you have !important on the same element with same specificity but at a file required below(which in your case is application.css and it doesn't have !important)

So first change OL, LI to **ol and li** and if you want to play around with the order in which your css files are required then in your app/assets/stylesheets/application.css file you can move ***= require_self**(this decides in which order your styles in application.css will be loaded). For details refer to [`Rails asset pipeline`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives)